# How to present statistics for QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a plugin for QGIS 2.18 where a user can obtain some statistics from a layer, something similar to this:

[image: Raster info]

The above tool can be accessed from the menubar:

```
Raster > Miscellaneous > Information
```

What kind of Qt object is the box above and how can I print information not only in a similar format but also in an efficient manner?

---

At the moment, I'm sending text to a [QTextBrowser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html) using something like:

```
self.dockwidget.textBrowser.setText(str('Layer name: ' + str(layer.name()) +
                            '\nDate: 20/02/2017' +
                            '\nSize: 5 Mb' + 
                            ...))
```

[image: Current report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) to create a list of items and set it to use alternating row colours:

```
listWidget = self.dockwidget.listWidget
listWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
layer_dict = {'  Layer name': layer.name(),
              '   Date': '20/02/2017',
              '    Size': '5 Mb'}

listWidget.clear()
row = 0
for key, value in layer_dict.items():
    listWidget.insertItem(row, key + ': ' + value)
    row = row + 1
```

---

Example:

[image: Example]